# Can't create HAS MANY relationship when foreign key AUTO INCREMENTS in parent table GORM 2.0

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

Exploring GORM 2.0's AutoMigrate which automatically creates constraints in the database, it throws this error when I use a foreign key that auto increments in it's parent table for HAS MANY relationship:

> Error 1075: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto
> column and it must be defined as a key

Here's the code:

```
type Person struct {
    ID      uint     `gorm:"primaryKey;type:INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"`
    Clothes *[]Cloth `gorm:"foreignKey:OwnerID;"`
}

type Cloth struct {
    ClothID uint `gorm:"primaryKey;type:INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT;"`
    OwnerID uint `gorm:"index;type:INT UNSIGNED;autoIncrement:false;"` //foreign key
    Color   string
}
```

In the main function:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&Person{})
db.AutoMigrate(&Cloth{})
```

OwnerID column (the foreign key) shouldn't increment but GORM won't let me create it like that.

I'm using a MySQL db.
Not sure if it's a bug, help please :)

Comment: There is no need to use auto-increment for foreign key.

Comment: Yes I don't want the foreign key to auto-increment in the table but gorm makes it do so.